# How to show 2 replies to 2 different users through one phone number

Tags: php, sms, gsm, modem

I have a website which allow user to send sms to any recipients.
If there are 2 users sent a message to a same recipient using a same phone number , 
user A send "Hello" to Mr.Dot.
user B send "How are you" to Mr.Dot too.

When Mr.Dot reply both of these messages , how can I show the only message to the correct user in the website?

Mr.Dot reply "Hi" to user A and "I'm fine" to user B.
How can user A read only the "Hi" and user B read only the "I'm fine"? Is it possible to do so?

Thanks for every reply .

Comment: why are all your users using the same phone number?

Comment: Just in case...I will put several numbers for it and all the messages will sent through random numbers , but there are few times that 2 users have the same recipient and randomly sent the message with same number , so when the recipient reply their message , both of the user can read the same message .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some SMS aggregation services allow you to perform SMS spoofing (specify a customer sender id or 'from' number). Some examples:

- http://support.clickatell.com/product_guides/clickatell/senderid.php
- http://www.nowsms.com/discus/messages/1/9398.html
- http://www.iwiz.in/bulk_sms_senderid.html

There tend to be some fairly restrictive uses applied to this (due to the potential abuse that it can be used for). Certain countries/states forbid spoofing so you'll need to check up on your local laws

You could, possibly, specify the cell phone number the message from User A was from his own number, so any replies go straight back to his own cellphone. And the same for User B.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
How if my website is using a gsm modem and own web server to sms ?
How can I apply this service to my website?

Comment: Ah, you need a direct bind to a SMSC if you want to set the sender id (or an aggregator who allows that option). If you're using a GSM modem, then your SMS will route to your operator and then go through their SMSC bind. You'll probably find they don't even offer the option of specifying a sender id. You may find that you need to tack something on the end of your SMS saying "To reply to this user, please start with 'bob:'" or something like that to identify which person the user is replying to.